# How to make a schema dependant of other schema

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Got a question and I don't find the answer, can someone help me ? here is the situation :

I have a schema, that is a template.

And I want to have 10 schemas of this template.

But I want that everytime I change the structure of the template schema, like making a new column, the column is created in all the schemas related to the template schema.

is this possible with Oracle ?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: I use Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: SQL Developer is an IDE that can be used to connect to multiple RDBMSes; it is not itself an RDBMS. What is the underlying RDBMS that you are using?

Comment: As described, no, this isn't a thing that exists in Oracle.  What is the business problem you are trying to solve, though?  I am hard-pressed to think of a situation where I would want to have 10 identical schemas in the same database.  If you are trying to do something where, say, you have 10 customers and want each customer to have a separate set of data, you'd probably want a single schema and to use VPD (virtual private database) to ensure that each customer has access to only their data.

Comment: I have to replace < a single schema of partioned tables by year > by < creating for each year a new schema without partition >

Comment: Why would you do that?  A single partitioned table is technically superior in every way to a bunch of tables in different schemas.  If you were going to put each partition in a separate physical table because you don't want to license partitioning, you'd generally want to create those tables in the same schema not different schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others said, it is not possible in Oracle to do this by default. BUT, if your on the latest versions (12.2 and higher), and don't mind paying for the multitenant option, you can look into something called [application containers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/multi/creating-removing-application-containers-seeds-with-sql-plus.html#GUID-E2B95068-D16D-438D-9A0B-974540988990). This will trade your schemas in a single DB for the same schema but in different PDBs. Application containers allows you to define the schema in a parent PDB (including tables, views, triggers, ....) and have every modification propagated to the PDBs (you sync each PDB when you want).

Comment: Due to a recent licensing update, Multitenant only requires $ if you create more than 3 pluggable databases. 10 is definitely more than 3 though...

Answer (score 0):

> But I want that everytime I change the structure of the template schema, like making a new column, the column is created in all the schemas related to the template schema.
>
> is this possible with Oracle ?

No, it is not. You would need to separately create the column in the table owned by each individual user (a.k.a. schema).

Answer (score 0):

As Justin Cave suggested, your problem is practically screaming for Oracle Partitioning.

If you do not have Partitioning licensed, there is still the old (but free!) approach of making a partitioned view.

In this approach, you would keep your historical tables unchanged (i.e., don't go back and add new columns to them).  Instead, you would create a partitioned view that includes each historical table (concatenated together via `UNION ALL`).  The view definition can provide values for newer columns that did not exist in the original table that year.

A partitioned view also has the benefits of

- Making it easy to report across multiple years
- "Partition pruning" -- skipping tables that are not of interest in a given query

Here is a walk through of the approach:

#### Create tables for 2019 and 2020 data

```
CREATE TABLE matt_data_2019 
  ( id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    creation_date DATE NOT NULL,
    data_column1 NUMBER,
    data_column2 VARCHAR2(200),
    CONSTRAINT matt_data_2019 PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT matt_data_2019_c1 CHECK ( creation_date BETWEEN to_date('01-JAN-2019','DD-MON-YYYY') AND to_date('01-JAN-2020','DD-MON-YYYY') - interval '1' second )
 );

CREATE TABLE matt_data_2020 
  ( id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    creation_date DATE NOT NULL,
    data_column1 NUMBER,
    data_column2 VARCHAR2(200),
    data_column3 DATE,  -- This is new for 2020
    CONSTRAINT matt_data_2020 PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT matt_data_2020_c1 CHECK ( creation_date BETWEEN to_date('01-JAN-2020','DD-MON-YYYY') AND to_date('01-JAN-2021','DD-MON-YYYY') - interval '1' second )
 );
```

Notice there is a new column for 2020 that does not exist in 2019.

#### Put some test data in to ensure accurate test results...

```
INSERT INTO matt_data_2019 ( id, creation_date, data_column1, data_column2 )
SELECT rownum id,
       to_date('01-JAN-2019','DD-MON-YYYY') + (dbms_random.value(0, 365*24*60*60-1) / (365*24*60*60)), -- Some random date in 2019
       dbms_random.value(0,1000),
       lpad('2019',200,'X')
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY rownum <= 100000;

INSERT INTO matt_data_2020 ( id, creation_date, data_column1, data_column2, data_column3 )
SELECT rownum id,
       to_date('01-JAN-2020','DD-MON-YYYY') + (dbms_random.value(0, 365*24*60*60-1) / (365*24*60*60)), -- Some random date in 2020
       dbms_random.value(0,1000),
       lpad('2020',200,'X'),
       to_date('01-JAN-2021','DD-MON-YYYY') + (dbms_random.value(0, 365*24*60*60-1) / (365*24*60*60)) -- Some random date in 2021
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY rownum <= 100000;
```

#### Gather statistics on both tables for accurate test results ...

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(user,'MATT_DATA_2019');
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(user,'MATT_DATA_2020');
```

#### Create a view that includes all the tables.

You would need to modify this view every time a new table was created.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW matt_data_v AS
  SELECT 2019 source_year,
         id, 
         creation_date, 
         data_column1, 
         data_column2, 
         NULL data_column3   -- data_column3 did not exist in 2019
  FROM   matt_data_2019
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2020 source_year,
         id, 
         creation_date, 
         data_column1, 
         data_column2, 
         data_column3   -- data_column3 did not exist in 2019
  FROM   matt_data_2020;
```

#### Check how Oracle will process a query specifying a single year

```
EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = 'MM' FOR SELECT * FROM MATT_DATA_V WHERE SOURCE_YEAR = 2020

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('PLAN_TABLE','MM'));
```

> ```
> Plan hash value: 393585474
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Operation            | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                |   110K|    15M|   620   (2)| 00:00:01 |
> |   1 |  VIEW                | MATT_DATA_V    |   110K|    15M|   620   (2)| 00:00:01 |
> |   2 |   UNION-ALL          |                |       |       |            |          |
> |*  3 |    FILTER            |                |       |       |            |          |
> |   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| MATT_DATA_2019 | 71238 |  9530K|   596   (2)| 00:00:01 |
> |   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | MATT_DATA_2020 |   110K|    15M|   620   (2)| 00:00:01 |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
> ---------------------------------------------------
>
>    3 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)
>
> Note
> -----
>    - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
> ```

#### Hmmm, it *looks* like Oracle is still including the 2019 table...

... but it isn't.  That `NULL IS NOT NULL` filter condition will cause Oracle to skip the 2019 table completely.

#### Prove that Oracle is skipping the 2019 table when we ask for 2020 data ...

```
alter session set statistics_level = ALL;

SELECT * FROM MATT_DATA_V WHERE SOURCE_YEAR = 2020;

-- Be sure to fetch entire result set (e.g., scroll to the end in SQL*Developer)

SELECT *
FROM   TABLE (DBMS_XPLAN.display_cursor (null, null,
                                         'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

> ```
> SQL_ID  1u3nwcnxs20jb, child number 0
> -------------------------------------
> SELECT * FROM MATT_DATA_V WHERE SOURCE_YEAR = 2020
>
> Plan hash value: 393585474
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Operation            | Name           | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                |      1 |        |    100K|00:00:00.21 |    5417 |
> |   1 |  VIEW                | MATT_DATA_V    |      1 |    110K|    100K|00:00:00.21 |    5417 |
> |   2 |   UNION-ALL          |                |      1 |        |    100K|00:00:00.17 |    5417 |
> |*  3 |    FILTER            |                |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
> |   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| MATT_DATA_2019 |      0 |  71238 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |
> |   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | MATT_DATA_2020 |      1 |    110K|    100K|00:00:00.09 |    5417 |
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
> ---------------------------------------------------
>
>    3 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)
>
> Note
> -----
>    - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
> ```

The results above show how Oracle skips the 2019 table when we don't ask for it.